# Why is it that a noun can be added with -ed?

Tags: word-formation

The question is raised from the viewpoint of a foreign language learner.

-ed is known to be added to a verb to mean past tense or past participle, but some phrases like **four-legged animals, winged birds**, are in the form of noun+-ed, why is it so? What is the logic behind such a structure?

Answer (score 8):

This comes about because it is not unusual to use *NOUN* as a verb meaning “to provide *[object]* with *NOUN*”

> We **bordered** the image (in red) = We supplied the image with a (red) border.
>   He **armed** the men (with swords) = He supplied the men with (swords as) arms.

The *-ed* suffix is thus a past-participle form with the passive sense “supplied with” or “equipped with”

> a **four-legged** animal is an animal supplied with four legs
>   a **winged** bird is a bird supplied with wings.