# "Turquoise-haired"—(-ed) suffix attached to a noun

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I found this sentence on [Complex](http://www.complex.com/pop-culture/2012/02/amber-rose-hangs-out-with-turquoise-haired-mystery-girl)

> Amber Rose hangs out with (a) **turquoise-haired** mystery girl.

I couldn't find 'turquoise-haired' in any dictionary, but a similar construction, "[dark-haired](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dark-haired)", has its place in Collin dictionary.

I don't understand how it's possible to attach the *-ed* suffix to a noun. Do we have a fancy term for this?

Comment: @StoneyB I wonder if there's any term we use for this.

Comment: @user178049 *CGEL* doesn't have a distinct name for adjectives (other than participles) formed specifically with *-ed*, but it calls the process, with whatever affix is employed, "adjectivalization" and the resulting words "denominal adjectives" or "denominals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as a **pseudo-participial** in *English Grammar: A University Course* (Downing and Locke, 2006). It's a form of participle derived from a noun. This participle is often modified to represent some non-essential feature.

> The true *-en participial* epithet derived from a verb [...] must be distinguished from **pseudo-participials**, which are derived from nouns [...]
>
> Such pseudo-participials are often modiﬁed, as the modiﬁcation represents some non-essential feature. We don’t say **a leaved plant*, **a haired girl*, because plants normally
>   have leaves and girls have hair. Not all leaves are big and not all girls’ hair is dark,
>   however, allowing the formation of big-leaved and dark-haired: a dark-haired girl. In *a
>   camera’ed bystander*, by contrast, no modiﬁer is needed because carrying a camera is
>   not an essential feature of a bystander.
>
> (p 436)

According to [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137052/why-is-it-that-a-noun-can-be-added-with-ed), this *- ed* suffix is a participle form with a passive sense "supplied with" or "equiped with".