# What is the difference between "high-pitched" and "high-pitch"

Tags: grammaticality, difference

I have noticed many compound adjectives with an "ed" ending, such as "snowed-under" or "three-legged". It looks a bit weird since I have also saw words like "high-price" and "high-quality" in some essays.

Is there any difference between those with and without an "ed" ending? Is there a principle about it? Or is it just somewhat idiomatic?

Comment: You can't be "high-qualitied", because "quality" is an adjective already. We only add -ed to verbs (*much-needed*) and nouns (*red-haired*) to make them into adjectives.

Comment: Since there are adjective like "three-stoery", which is not followed by "ed", can I say "I have a red-hair child"? Or is it just idiomatic that some should be followed by "ed" while the other shouldn't?

Comment: You can't say "red-hair child", or at least native English speakers say this very rarely. So it seems to be idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The past participle of the verb can be used adjectivally, whether alone, in combination with some agent, or with a preposition, or with an adverb:

> The door was newly **painted**.
>
> The sweater was moth-**eaten**.
>
> The game was **rained**-out. Too many rained-out games lately.
>
> They ate some slow-**cooked** BBQ brisket.
>
> The commodities trading floor is a very fast-**paced** environment.

The sweater had been eaten by moths.  It was raining so heavily the game had to be cancelled. The BBQ brisket had been cooked very slowly.

You will also see compound nouns used as adjectival modifiers:

> This new margarine tastes as good as the high-price spread.
>
> Her young son plays slow-pitch baseball.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from whether we considering a verb or a noun; the action that resulted in something, or the thing itself. It does get a bit more complicated because we're using these constructs as modifiers

> a high-pitched voice
>
> his voice had a surprisingly high pitch

but to focus just on the noun/verb concept:

I can choose the tone of my voice, I can choose a pitch (noun). I can pitch (verb) my voice.

When we are using the word **pitch** as a verb its past tense is **pitched**. So describing the sound we can say

> Her voice was high pitched

we are hearing the result of a speaker pitching their voice.

Similarly snow can be a noun or a verb. We can say

> Snow (noun) has fallen.
>
> It has snowed.

Note that snow in this usage is an impersonal verb, there is no actual subject in the sentence; it is a kind of place holder.

However (as Peter Shor has observed) there is another way in which the -ed may used, as a direct addition to a noun. Examples:

> Brown-eyed girl
>
> Broad-leaved plant

These are pseudo-participials, which are derived from nouns. I refer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141203/turquoise-haired-ed-suffix-attached-to-a-noun) in our sister site at the quotation from Downing and Locke, mentioned there.

> Such pseudo-participials are often modiﬁed, as the modiﬁcation
>   represents some non-essential feature. We don’t say *a leaved plant,
>   *a haired girl, because plants normally have leaves and girls have hair. Not all leaves are big and not all girls’ hair is dark, however,
>   allowing the formation of big-leaved and dark-haired: a dark-haired
>   girl. In a camera’ed bystander, by contrast, no modiﬁer is needed
>   because carrying a camera is not an essential feature of a bystander.
>
> (p 436)

Comment: But you can be *white-haired* and *red-haired*, and *hair* is not a verb.

Comment: @ Peter Shor - very good point. It was interesting to find the additional information.

Comment: It seems a bit idiomatic. Is it correct to say "a high-priced product", "a high-price product" or both?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by idiomatic. Less formal? Slang? I think the modifier-noun-ed construct is quite normal. An example from Shakespeare: Portia in the Merchent of Venice uses the phrase "green-eyed monster". A different construct "monster with green eyes" sounds clumsy in comparison.

Comment: As for high-price and high-priced: both can be used. I'm not able to articulate the different contexts in which I would use each. "I can tell the difference between butter and the high-price spread." Seems fine, but for some reason I would use "high-priced" instead, and I can't say why!