# Why do we say "a one-legged man", with a final -ed, but also say "a one-person job" without?

Tags: grammar, difference, compounds, suffixes, word-formation

Why do we say "a one-legged man", with a final "-ed", but also say "a one-person job" without the "-ed"? We also say:

> A two-minute walk.
>
> A six-hour flight.

But then we say:

> A green-eyed woman
>
> Black-eyed peas

When I think about it, it seems to me the pattern with a final *-d/-ed* suggests the idea of *having*, as in *having green eyes*. But this theory doesn't seem to work with some other compound adjectives like:

> A two-storey building

It should be two-storeyed because it means made of or having two storeys.

Comment: Related: [Why is it that a noun can be added with -ed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/137052/9161)

Answer (score 10):

The past participle formed from a part of the body(eye, arm, leg, foot, etc) means "having said body part", as you say; a number in front indicates how many there are:

> a three-legged stool
>
> a one-eyed pirate
>
> a four-armed deity
>
> a seven-headed dragon
>
> a three-headed dog

With *units of measure* we do not do this; rather we use the unit of measure in the singular:

> a twelve-inch ruler
>
> a six-hour flight

With buildings, **storey** can be understood as unit of measure or as a component of the building, so that both are possible:

> a ten-storey building
>
> three-storeyed terraces
>
> storeyed dwellings

P.S. In American English, **storey** can be spelled **storey** or **story**.

Comment: But "Storyed" is wrong in any dialect of English.

Comment: This would be improved by addressing the specific example given, and pointing out that "person" is being used as a measure of how big the job is (not as a countable property of the job).

Comment: @Beanluc: Go for it. Then it would be a two-answered question. Or would that be two-answer question?  Hmmm...

Comment: Technically, it's a bit wider than just number. You can also say "a blue-eyed pirate", "a bare-legged person", etc.

Comment: @Beanluc https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/storeyed _Having the stated number of storeys (building levels)_

Comment: A good example might be "A one-man boat" vs "a manned boat". The implication in the second in this case would be that someone is currently in the boat.

Comment: @Beanluc [Really?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/storeyed)

Comment: I disagree with `storey` as "American English". Can't say I've ever seen this spelling (besides as a typo) and `ngrams` seems to agree https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=storey%2Cstory&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=1800&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cstorey%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BStorey%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstorey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cstory%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstory%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStory%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Beanluc "Storyed" is, but "storied" isn't (as usual).

Comment: @Roland Heath: Interesting example with the *manned* and *one-man* boat.  I think **manned**, while it could indeed mean "with human beings operating it or on it *currently*", is not limited to that very specific meaning; the sense of "currently" is imparted by context. Compare "manned vehicle" versus "unmanned vehicle", where "unmanned" means "designed so that there are no humans on board" and "manned" means "designed so that one or more human operators must be on board". Context tells us whether there is an implication of "currently" or "at this moment".

Comment: Storied or storeyed, right. Not storyed.